# TS1005 and 1109 errors

Tags: typescript

ERROR in src/environments/environment.ts(7,14): error TS1005: ',' expected.
lafs-web  | src/environments/environment.ts(8,1): error TS1109: Expression expected.

export const environment = {
production: false,
api_url: 'http://localhost:3000'
};

^that is the whole code
update: i am using ts version 5.1.6